# Pycord slash commands delete themselves after usage

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

In pycord, whenever I run my command /note, it deletes all of my slash commands from the bot except for the first one I register in my code. I can reset the command by rerunning my script, but then the same thing happens.

I have written all of my slash commands to the same guild, and they are set up the same way.

```py
@client.slash_command(name = "rgb", description = "set my rgb light", guild=discord.Object(id=1087167885748736030)) 
async def rgb(interaction, r: int, g: int, b: int):
   rgbcolor={
       'red': r,
       'green': g,
       'blue': b
   }
   rgbstring=json.dumps(rgbcolor)
   arduino.write(bytes(rgbstring, 'utf-8')) #writes objects to an arduino
   await interaction.respond(f"LED has been made rgb({r}, {g}, {b})")


@client.slash_command(name = "rickroll", description = "rickroll me", guild=discord.Object(id=1087167885748736030)) #Add the guild ids in which the slash command will appear. If it should be in all, remove the argument, but note that it will take some time (up to an hour) to register the command if it's for all guilds.
async def rickroll(interaction):
   rgbcolr={
       'rolled': "l+ratio"
   }
   rgbstrig=json.dumps(rgbcolr)
   arduino.write(bytes(rgbstrig, 'utf-8'))
   await interaction.respond("Now I have to sit through that")


@client.slash_command(name = "note", description = "Play a note on my arduino (pick a number between 1500 and 5000)", guild=discord.Object(id=1087167885748736030)) 
async def note(interaction, htz: int):
    rbcolor={
        'note': htz
    }
    if htz>5000 or htz<1500:
        await interaction.respond("Too low or too high!")
    else:
        rbstring=json.dumps(rbcolor)
        arduino.write(bytes(rbstring, 'utf-8'))
        notes = ['A', 'A#', 'B', 'C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#']

        note_number = 12 * math.log2(htz / 440) + 49  
        note_number = round(note_number)
            
        note = (note_number - 1 ) % len(notes)
        note = notes[note]

        octave = (note_number + 8 ) // len(notes)
        await interaction.respond(f"You played a {note} on octave {octave}")
    #After running this command, it deletes all of my other code.
```

My bot has full permissions

Comment: This can happen if multiple instances of the bot are running. Is that the case?

Comment: @BlueRobin I solved it by restarting my computer, so maybe